# Open and close a tag in two different conditions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
{ null !== label && <FormLabel text={label} /> }
{ null !== icon && <FormIcon icon={icon} /> }
```

**It works well**

```
{ null !== icon && <InputGroup> }
    <Test>
        Hello
    </Test>
{ null !== icon && </InputGroup> }
```

**I have a SyntaxError**

I do not think I have the right to open and close a tag in two different conditions, but I need it

Answer (score 1):

This is an invalid syntax. But you can give `InputGroup` a conditional definition by declaring it using a `ternary operator`

```
const Comp = icon !== null ? InputGroup : React.Fragment

return(
    <Comp>
        <span/>
    </Comp>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way is better?

```
{
  null !== icon ? (
    <InputGroup>
      <Test>Hello</Test>
    </InputGroup>
  ) : (
    <Test>Hello</Test>
  );
}
```

or this:

```
const test = <Test>Hello</Test>;

{
  null !== icon ? <InputGroup>{test}</InputGroup> : test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second aspect as per you code is syntactically incorrect, as you cannot make a conditional view on its end and start tag as its is not posiible here, alternatively what you can do just make a custom code below,

**You can use ternary operator :**

```
a > b ? a : b
```

**Code :**

```
{
    null !== icon ?
        <InputGroup>
            <Test>
                Hello
            </Test>
        </InputGroup> :
            <Test>
                Hello
            </Test>
}
```

I hope this helps....Thanks :)